# Structural pattern matching in python <3.10

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10, structural-pattern-matching

To use the | operator in <3.10, one can do `from __future__ import annotations`. Is something similar possible for structural pattern matching, i.e. writing things like

```
match x:
    case 1:
        print("x is 1")
    case 2:
        print("x is 2")
```

Comment: The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__future__.html) don't seem to suggest you can.

Comment: `from __future__` is mostly about giving you a way to switch on a breaking change in advance. That doesn't apply to structural pattern matching, which doesn't change how any existing code should behave.